# displaying detailed form based on textbox value and a button

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

i have a form named "search" with 2 textboxes,datagridview and a buttton. when i enter any keyword such as a name i want into the first textbox ["txtemployee_search"], it filters the datagridview [dgvemployee]items which is binded to the employee table.so when i select the name im looking for, it shows up in the second textbox["txtemp_search_selection"].but MY PROBLEM IS, I WANT TO SHOW OR OPEN A SECOND FORM CONTAINING THE DETAILS like name,age,sex,picture,phone,etc which are related to the name in the second textbox WHEN I CLICK THE BUTTON. im using vb 2008 and sql server 2005.I NEED HELP PLS!!!

***below is my code***

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class employee_search
'THE CODE TO SEARCH DATAGRID WHILE TYPING INTO FIRST TEXTBOX

Private Sub txtemployee_search_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtemployee_search.TextChanged
    Dim keywords As String = txtemployee_search.Text

    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=oheneba;Initial Catalog=brainiac;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********")

    ' Use wildcard  

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Full_Name Like '%" & keywords & "%' ", con)

    ' or Where Full_Name='" & keywords & "'  

    con.Open()

    Dim myDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()

    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Employee")

    dgvemployee.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("Employee").DefaultView
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

'CODE TO DISPLAY SELECTED DATAGRIDVIEW ITEM INTO THE SECOND TEXTBOX

```
Private Sub dgvemployee_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvemployee.CellContentClick
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim thisCell As DataGridViewCell = dgv.SelectedCells(0)
    Dim selCell As Integer = thisCell.ColumnIndex

    txtemp_search_selection.Text = dgvemployee.CurrentRow.Cells(selCell).Value.ToString()

End Sub
```

Comment: Watch for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

The approch is a bit diffrent that you should choose.
Sorry if i'm wrong but i'll wive you an example with 2 grids. one with customers and one with orders (the relation must be right on the DB). So use 2 BindingSource objects. one with Customers and one with Orders.
so we have

- CustomersBindingSource
- OrdersBindingSource

Set on property window

```
CustomersBindingSource.Datasource = yourDataset
CustomersBindingSource.DataMember = Customers
OrdersBindingSource.Datasource = OrdersCustomersfkBindingSource
```

and about filtering the way that i suggest is this one:
CustomersBindingSource.filter = "Customername like " & txtCustomFilter
i'm in a little hurry now.. but if you have more questions i'll be happy to help you.

Comment: also load on dataset both  tables  and be sure that the dataset will have the relation on it.
 Me.OrdersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Orders)
 Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Customers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want additional details in another form, then what you need to do is create the second form with the details.  Add in databinding, just like you did for the datagridview, and navigate to the correct record.  You should be able to pass the full name selected from the datagridview into the new form.

```
    tIndex = Me.MyBindingSource.Find("Full_Name", keywords)
    If tIndex = -1 Then 'could not find
        'employee not found
    Else
        Me.MyBindingSource.Position = tIndex 'navigate to found record
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

> CODE TO DISPLAY SELECTED DATAGRIDVIEW ITEM INTO THE SECOND TEXTBOX

Try this ..

```
txtemp_search_selection.Text = dgvemployee.CurrentCell.Value
```